# stdio.h вывод в консоль с возможностью редактирования

Tags: c++, потоки-данных, консоль, fstream

столкнулся с необходимостью подавать пользователю на ввод некоторую строку. Строку выводить получается, на то есть fputs, puts, fwrite. Но вот возможность редактирования пользователем этой самой строки не предусмотрено. Помогите пожалуйста что юзать? Библиотека stdio, кросплатформенность (c++).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите [GNU readline](https://linux.die.net/man/3/readline).

Кстати, bash (и многие другие интерактивные неграфические утилиты) используют ее (вместе с [GNU history](https://linux.die.net/man/3/history)).

Краткое описание `readline` есть [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline), там же есть ссылки на аналогичные библиотеки.

Comment: Спасибо, за помощь, но я реализовал данный функционал с помощью WriteConsoleInput. К сожалению readline никак не хочет ужиться с isql

Comment: @СеменРоманов, наверное это какие-то виндовые заморочки (переходите в \*nix)